# Meaning of "\b" in the below regex using grep?

Tags: regex

I just saw a [post](http://www.shellhacks.com/en/RegEx-Find-Email-Addresses-in-a-File-using-Grep) where the regex to search for email addresses in a text file is given by:

```
grep -E -o "\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}\b" file.txt
```

I wanted to know the meaning of the `\b` at the start and the end.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

*The metacharacter \b is an anchor like the caret and the dollar sign. It matches at a position that is called a "word boundary". This match is zero-length.* ...

*Simply put: \b allows you to perform a "whole words only" search using a regular expression in the form of \bword\b. A "word character" is a character that can be used to form words. All characters that are not "word characters" are "non-word characters".*